# MVVM vs MVC in ASP.net : Either better for busy websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm

I'm wondering about the underlying implementations of these design patterns specifically within asp.net. Is there a difference between the two models in terms of scalability of a website (i.e. as traffic increases might I regret following one or both of these design patterns)? I ask as someone once mentioned that MVC produces a 'lighter' website but I can find nothing to back this up.

If MVVM is as good as MVC why did MS release all the MVC tools?

Thank you

Comment: Something to keep in mind - nothing is "as good as" another. They are simply different. Is a screwdriver "as good as" a hammer?

Comment: @Rex M : I thought the question made it plain I was concerned about scalability.

Comment: that's my point. Both scale in different ways. Scalability is orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are both adequate and will scale appropriately.

The significant difference is that MVVM lends itself to making use of the native bi-directional binding functionality within the .NET framework. MVC is prevalent within ASP.NET whereas MVVM is prevalent within SL/WPF.

Neither is right or wrong; the underlying technology is the largest factor in the decision process.

Comment: Ah, I though MVVM could be used directly from asp.net! My mistake.